# How to add a pipeline variable of object type in an Azure DevOps classic pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I have developed Azure Logic Apps using Visual Studio Code. In the logic app's `template.json` I used the following object type parameter.

```
  "Object_One": {
  "type": "object",
  "defaultValue": {
    "Demo1": 123,
    "Demo2": 456,
    "Demo3": 789
  },
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The Demo object"
  }
}
```

I have configured CI and CD pipelines in Azure DevOps to deploy the logic app templates. But I want to override the value of the above object type parameter in Azure DevOps CI and CD pipelines.

Is it possible to add a pipeline variable of object type in an Azure DevOps classic pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) task in your classic or YAML pipeline to replace the *tokens* in any target file(s). An example using YAML pipeline is as follows:

```
- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@5
  displayName: 'Replace tokens in template.json'
  inputs:
    targetFiles: template.json
    tokenPattern: azpipelines
    escapeType: custom
    charsToEscape: '"'
```

your `template.json` would look like this:

```
  "Object_One": {
  "type": "object",
  "defaultValue": $(objectJSON),
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The Demo object"
  }
}
```

You can define `objectJSON` as a pipeline variable or in the variable groups. For example:

[image]

Comment: Sibtain, I want to pass different values to the above parameter from Azure DevOps CI variables.

Comment: Can you give any example of the how the values would look like when passing into the ADO variables?

Comment: I am passing values in pipeline variables like `{"Demo1":123,"Demo2":456,"Demo3":789}`

Comment: @Pradeep I have updated my answer as per your requirements.

Comment: @Pradeep please accept the answer if this fulfills your use case.